# animate background color multiple times.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to animate the background color of a div multiple times on different scrolltop value. 
Below is the code I have, but it only changes the color once (it only listens to the second one.)
can anyone help?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
         if($(window).scrollTop() >=200){
             $('#div01').stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#fff" },500);
         }
         else{
             $('#div01').stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#333" },500); 
         }
});
 $(window).scroll(function() {
         if($(window).scrollTop() >=500){
             $('#div01').stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#777" },500);
         }
         else{
             $('#div01').stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#fff" },500); 
         }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling that your second `$(window).scroll()` is overriding the first one. The following code should work.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
         if($(window).scrollTop() >= 500){
             $('#div01').stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#777" },500);
         }
         else if($(window).scrollTop() >=200){
             $('#div01').stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#fff" },500);
         }
         else{
             $('#div01').stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#333" },500); 
         }
});
```

In any case, this is a more DRY version of your code.

Comment: [example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/ypQBS/2/) w/some refactoring.  You could even add additional optimization for when there is no change (and no animation needs to trigger)

Answer (score 2):

Give another condition for your first `if` to check if `$(window).scrollTop()` less than `500`:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() >=200 && $(window).scrollTop() < 500){
    $('#div01').stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#fff" },500);
}
else{
    $('#div01').stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#333" },500); 
}
```

Comment: thank you felix. it works!!! but it doesn't change back to the very first color I start off with when I scroll to the top. any suggestion?

Comment: because you don't have any condition to check when `$(window).scrollTop()` less than `200`. You should add another condition to achieve it